# Decorator pattern example in HeadFirst book vs storing objects in a container

Tags: c++, oop

I am reading Decorator pattern in Head First Design Patterns, and have also gone thru few examples on internet related to it.

I have a doubt understanding its relevance.

Suppose for coffee class example in book, we have condiments for coffee decorate ( or wrap ) the coffee class and call getCost() function, which in turn will call the getCost() functioin from coffee class.

But rather, I would prefer to have my coffee class store the condiment objects in a vector and calculate total cost by calling getCost() method of all the condiments in that vector.

What am I missing here, is there any loophole in this design?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: All those Animals, Coffees and Shapes usually make very little sense. I would love to the software development books to sport relevant software examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the description here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern to be helpful in grasping the basics of the pattern. I recommend reading through it, but here are some things I gleaned that may give you the basic answer:

1. There are cases where you need functionality on an object from your class tree without needing it on every object, and adding that functionality to a base class for a narrow set of cases would lead to code bloat, while adding it to multiple (but not all) subclasses that need the capability would cause code duplication of be a configuration management headache.
2. There are cases where you do not have control over the structure of the classes you are using and do not have the luxury of extending them directly, as you suggested in your question.
3. In situations where you have multiple optional behaviors you want to be able to add to an object, doing subclass inheritance becomes increasingly difficult as you have to create subclasses for all combinations of the options.